# Does Akka automatically copy over variables when an actor fails

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-supervision

In **Akka Cookbook** by Héctor Veiga Ortiz, the reader is told that

> When an actor throws an exception, it sends a message to the supervisor, and the supervisor handles the failure by restarting that actor. It clears out the accumulated state of the actor, and creates a fresh new actor, means, it then restores the last value assigned to the state of old actor to the preRestart value.

However, I tried testing the following code, which suggests that what the author says isn't true.

```
import akka.actor._
import akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy._
import akka.util.Timeout
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.pattern.ask

case object Error
case class StopActor(actorRef: ActorRef)
case object Inc

class LifeCycleActor extends Actor {
  var sum = 1
  override def preRestart(reason: Throwable, message: Option[Any]):Unit =
    println(s"sum in preRestart is $sum")
  override def preStart(): Unit = println(s"sum in preStart is $sum")
  def receive = {
    case Inc => sum += 1
    case Error => throw new ArithmeticException()
    case _ => println("default msg")
  }
  override def postStop(): Unit =
    println(s"sum in postStop is ${sum * 3}")
  override def postRestart(reason: Throwable): Unit = {
    sum = sum * 2
    println(s"sum in postRestart is $sum")
  }
}

class Supervisor extends Actor {
  override val supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 10, withinTimeRange = 1 minute){
    case _: ArithmeticException => Restart
    case t =>
      super.supervisorStrategy.decider.applyOrElse(t, (_:Any)=>Escalate)
  }
  def receive = {
    case (props: Props, name: String) => sender ! context.actorOf(props, name)
    case StopActor(actorRef) => context.stop(actorRef)
  }
}

object ActorLifeCycle extends App {
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(2 seconds)
  val actorSystem = ActorSystem("Supervision")
  val supervisor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[Supervisor], "supervisor")
  val childFuture = supervisor ? (Props(new LifeCycleActor), "LifeCycleActor")
  val child = Await.result(childFuture.mapTo[ActorRef], 2 seconds)
  child ! Inc
  child ! Error
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  supervisor ! StopActor(child)
}
```

The output I get is as follows.

> sbt:chpt2_ActorLifeCycle> runMain ActorLifeCycle
>   sum in preStart is 1
>   sum in preRestart is 2
>   [ERROR] [11/08/2018 20:06:01.423]
>   [Supervision-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4]
>   [akka://Supervision/user/supervisor/LifeCycleActor] null
>   java.lang.ArithmeticException
>   sum in postRestart is 2
>   sum in postStop is 6

If what the author says is true, the final value should be double what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I guess you forget to add `sum += 1` when receive message `Inc` in child actor when post the question, please modify. Otherwise, as I test, you cannot get your output.

Next explain your code:

From next diagram, you can see the `preReStart` is called on old instance, not on new instance.

[image]

There is also a desc about this, detail [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#restart-hooks)

> 1. The old actor is informed by calling preRestart with the exception which caused the restart and the message which triggered that exception; the latter may be None if the restart was not caused by processing a message, e.g. when a supervisor does not trap the exception and is restarted in turn by its supervisor, or if an actor is restarted due to a sibling’s failure. If the message is available, then that message’s sender is also accessible in the usual way (i.e. by calling sender). This method is the best place for cleaning up, preparing hand-over to the fresh actor instance, etc. By default it stops all children and calls postStop.
> 2. The initial factory from the actorOf call is used to produce the fresh instance.
> 3. The new actor’s postRestart method is invoked with the exception which caused the restart. By default the preStart is called, just as in the normal start-up case.

So, for your example:

- when call `preRestart`, it print the sum of old actor, that is `2`, notice: you have inc it.
- when call `postRestart`, it print the sum of new actor, that is the initial value `1` with the calculation `sum = sum * 2`, finally print `2`, not `4`. The `Inc message` just receive on old instance, not on new instance.

Finally, the content of the book:

> When an actor throws an exception, it sends a message to the supervisor, and the supervisor handles the failure by restarting that actor. It clears out the accumulated state of the actor, and creates a fresh new actor, means, it then restores the last value assigned to the state of old actor to the preRestart value.

I think what you concern is `it then restores the last value assigned to the state of old actor to the preRestart value`. I don't quite know what it means, if you just think it assign the last value of old actor to `preRestart` function, then it is correct, as it just run on old instance, otherwise, it seems conflict with akka official guide & experiment; And, if want to restore the value, we may had to use `resume` not `restart`.
Anyway, I think we should use the akka offical document as a standard, and understand the correct logic.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the missing code in Inc. I removed it for testing purposes. Your answer is very helpful.